# React ag grid - event to find if user reached end of grid while scrolling

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-ng2, ag-grid-react

In ag-grid, we have 'bodySroll' event to listen scrolling.
But I want to know when user reaches last record of grid while scrolling.

Is there any way I can acheive this?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add onScroll listener for the Div which holds your ag-grid and then you can use gridApi.getLastDisplayedRow() this gives you last row index in the current viewport you can use this index to compare with your total number of records present on the current grid 
if((gridApi.getLastDisplayRow()+1) == totalRecords). In order to update  gridApi.getLastDisplayRow()+1 value you need to write it inside onScroll listener function.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone trying to do this with horizontal scrolling, instead of vertical, this solution worked for me (ag-grid-community and ag-grid-react 29.3.3):

```
const handleVirtualColumnsChanged = (e: BodyScrollEvent) => {
  const columnApi = e.columnApi;
  const allColumns = columnApi.getAllGridColumns();
  const allDisplayedColumns = columnApi.getAllDisplayedVirtualColumns();
  const lastColumn = allColumns[allColumns.length - 1];
  const colId = lastColumn.getColId();

  if (allDisplayedColumns.find((col) => col.getColId() === colId)) {
    console.log(' Final column scrolled to');
  }
};

return (
  <div style={{ height: 'calc(100vh - 230px)' }}>
    <div style={{ height: '100%' }} className='ag-theme-balham'>
      <AgGridReact
        onVirtualColumnsChanged={handleVirtualColumnsChanged}
        {...allYourOtherProps}
      />
    </div>
  </div>
)
```