# Is there any method through which I can know whether I have reached the end of the record while scrolling in Ag -grid?

Tags: reactjs, scrollbar, ag-grid

I want to show a message when I have reached the end of the records while scrolling in Ag-grid  . Is there any way to do this ?

I have tried to use the onBodyScroll event but it gets triggered every time I try to scroll . It is not detecting the end of records .

Thanks in advance .

Comment: Check this answer to a similar question:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/52644551

Answer (score 0):

Give Ref to the container and onScroll ,fire a method as written below

**JSX**

```
<div ref="container" onScroll={this.onScrollDiv} >
   <div>data</div>
   <div>data</div>
   <div>data</div>
   <div>data</div>
   <div>data</div>
   <div>data</div>
   <div>data</div>
   <div>data</div>
</div>
```

**method**

```
onScrollDiv = () => {
    let element = this.refs.container;

    if (
      element.scrollTop / (element.scrollHeight - element.clientHeight) ===
      1
    ) {
      console.log("reached bottom ,do something else");
    }
  };
```

Comment: This is not working for me , as the scrollTop value remains 0 and scrollHeight and clientHeight remains 200 . It does not change even when I reach the end of the records .